# Copy recursive files of all the subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to copy all the log files from a directory which does not contain log files, but it contains other subdirectories with log files. These subdirectories also contain other subdirectories, so I need something recursive.

I tried

```
cp -R *.log /destination
```

But it doesn't work because the first directory does not contains log files. The response can be also a loop in bash.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /path/to/logdir  -type f -name "*.log"  |xargs -I {}  cp {} /path/to/destinationdir
```

Explanation:

```
find searches recursively
-type f tells you to search for files
-name specifies the name pattern
xargs executes commands
-I {} indicates an argument substitution symbol
```

Another version without xargs:

```
find /path/to/logdir -type f -name '* .log' -exec cp '{}' /path/to/destinationdir \;
```